# marginpar anchored by pages not by text

Tags: marginpar

I'm using `marginpar` to put margin figures in a document - there are $n$ pages and $n$ figures so I'd like to have one on each page, anchored to the first line of text on each page - at the moment I put them in in roughly the right place with

```
\marginpar{
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[angle=270,width=\marginparwidth]{images/diagram.pdf}
\caption{mycaption}
\label{mylabel}
\end{figure}
}
```

but when I add or remove text they get moved around unpleasantly - is there a way I can enforce with say `\marginpar[page=1]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not put a `figure` in a `marginpar`; your posted code would produce the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
```

To include an image at the same point in each page you could use something like

```
\makeatletter
\def\@ooddhead{\hfill
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(0,-50){\includgraphics{file\thepage}}
\end{picture}
\makeatother
```

This will include the file file1.pdf on the first page, the file file2.pdf on second, etc.

Comment: Um - code putting figure in marginpar does does work - I should point out I'm using the style file {chi-ext} for extended abstracts... (and the figure in the marginpar is included in the sample file...) the files are at http://chi2012.acm.org/chi2012extendedformatLaTeX.zip

Comment: Standard latex figure environment will not work there, if you are using non standard definitions without telling anyone it is hard to help. It _always_ helps to post _complete_ small documents in your question showing all packages used.